# Determine action according to previous scene in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have the following script:

```
void Update() 
{
    //timed
    sc = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("timedScore");
    score.text = sc.ToString();
    //arcade
    sc = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("arcadeScore");
    score.text = sc.ToString();
}
```

And I want to execute the timed statement if my previous scene was 1 and arcade if my previous scene was 2.

I tried using the `SceneManager`, but it seems that it doesn't have a function for determining previous scene. Or is there some other way, since my game has timed and arcade mode so I want to load the score of the correct previous scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SceneManager.GetActiveScene()` function is very useful for this. It is used to get information about the **current** scene.

Before you load another scene, you have to get the current scene then save its name.

```
string currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastScene", currentScene);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Now, you can freely load another scene.

---

To check the last scene from the newly loaded scene, read the *"LastScene"* key.

```
//Read Last scene
string lastScene = PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastScene", null);
if (lastScene != null)
{
    if (lastScene == "blahblahblah")
    {
        //Do something
    }

    if (lastScene == "Otherblahblahblah")
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

This could have been easily done with `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex` but I didn't use this because `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex` returns `-1` if the the scene is loaded from AssetBundle.

Comment: Could also use a non-monobehaviour script to store lastActiveScene (e.g. static globals) or a monobehavior attached to a `DontDestroyOnLoad` object. PlayerPrefs *works* but feels "odd."

Comment: Yes, that's right. `DontDestroyOnLoad` should work fine. As for `PlayerPrefs `, if it is a single or just few variables, `PlayerPrefs` is fine. If it is a large data like game settings, playerinfo or object infos then use data structure+json/xml/binary+C# File API.

Comment: Oh sure, it *works* it just feels weird (I normally consider it for things that are actually *options* that the player wants to persist from session to session: like whether the game is muted). That's all I meant.

Comment: Sorry, you mean you consider DontDestroyOnLoad  or PlayerPrefs for things that are actually options that the player wants to persist from session to session?

Comment: Er, poorly worded comment is poorly worded. `s/it/PlayerPrefs/`

Comment: Oh ok.  I was a bit confused. Depending on the game, "options" can actually be a many variables and it's weird to save them one by one with PlayerPrefs . It makes more sense to use a class to serialize the data. PlayerPrefs can be used for anything. It just that people complain about it thrashing the registry so we only use it for saving small data.

Comment: I do think "mute" is on the category of "GameSettings" and that should have a dedicated class that holds the Game Settings. Looks more like an opinion but that's more efficient when you need to backup the values.

Comment: Sure, sure. All of that I can agree with (I haven't actually used PlayerPrefs for *anything* in...rather a long time). :)

Comment: Same. Used it to learn Unity with one of those Unity Project tutorials. Haven't used it since then again. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer Thank you